# Spread operator not type safe

Tags: typescript, spread

I have a function that is supposed to return some type but using the spread operator caused it to assign a misspelled key.

```
interface State {
    fieldA: number,
    fieldB: string
}

const reducer: (state: State, action: {payload: string}) => State = (state, action) => {

    // please note that those variables are not desired
    const tmp = { ...state, feildB: action.payload }; // No compile time error, :(

    // This is too verbose... but works
    const tmp2 = Object.assign<State, Partial<State>>(state, {feildB: action.payload}) // ERROR - this is what I need
    return tmp
}
const t = reducer({fieldA: 1, fieldB: 'OK'}, {payload: 'Misspelled'}) // Misspelled
console.log("feildB", (t as any).feildB) // Misspelled
console.log("fieldB", (t as any).fieldB) // OK
```

Is there a way to make it typesafe, while keeping the boilerplate to the minimum?

[Playground code HERE](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=51#code/FAAjISwOwFwUwE4DMCGBjOIDKMXxAN6jglIRwA2AJgIIBcIUArgLYBGiANMSWGZVQBCDAM4wE0AOY8QAXxky0AeyhiQCOFSYYEDABRi8cBjiOcQ6GBBUMCABxQBPCkpRVR4qbICUIALwAfNi4%20H4gBiFw5pbWUL6BhDIkyqowIDAsdv6EIAB0%20Ybw5khwENTCFmhWKrkOzq5UcgDcIAD0rSAAckogypllmFYsmIgISgjRIiAAkiAA7kpM1CBwAB52cFXASeDtIAAqABYQUyfpSj0AbohsSiJw%20bkgbExpCwgA1lMoU2sbVZodmAUmoMnYAEzZADybAAVpsYLkfiIIJIoAAeUxFEAABRQCCsKAomMiAQCETMhBKZSEDBiNTqLjcPjaHQAogAlDlQjkgAC06WOpymc0OeBmjDggN44A0MCYCCg6UyMnkJEUKlB2Q0Wh0egI-Go9BAAEZiuRygwAORQgDSVtk5nsTiZ7hAVoAsicRBsKBRNA7fHsvSIfZR-VQNaolP7ci5JHoAETU8qJ8x6NI-CxQRzeXIpoRBjohsN%206XgEExh7xpOGoRp8KZ745vN1wRFkB2oA)

Answer (score 5):

TypeScript is doing what it is supposed to do. In your case, you are creating a new object `tmp` with a new type that has 3 fields, namely:

```
interface State {
    fieldA: number;
    fieldB: string;
}
interface Tmp {
    fieldA: string;
    fieldB: string;
    payload: string;
}
```

In other words, the spread operator performs the following operation:

```
interface Obj {
    [key: string]: any;
}

const spread = (...objects: Obj[]) => {
    const merged: Obj = {};

    objects.forEach(obj => {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => merged[k] = obj[k]);
    });

    return merged;
}
```

The spread operator is creating a new type of object for you; if you want to infer the type, then you should do:

```
// this now throws an error
const tmp: State = { ...state, feildB: action.payload };
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however, introducing variables here was just to show that it will be Ok and the second one will not be Ok. I do not want to have additional variables here. If I just return the first version it will conform to state without highlighting the error.

Comment: This is not a bug/limitation of TypeScript. It's just how the spread operator works. It takes many objects, spreads them, and then merges them. So you should either use `Object.assign` or use `const tmp: State` or `const tmp = ... as State`. There are no other options.