# Why are Typescript key/value types lost when used with spread operator in object literals

Tags: typescript, types

```
const foo : {[key:string]:string} = {'hello': 'world', 'hi': 'there'};
const bar : number = 42
const foobar = {...foo, bar}
console.log(foobar)
// { hello: 'world', hi: 'there', bar: 42 }
```

The type of `foobar` resolves to `{bar: number}`. Why is this? I would expect the type of `foobar` to be `{[key:string]: string|number}` or `{[key:string]: string} & {bar: number}`

---

EDIT: I'm particularly confused on why in some cases the types are determined correctly:

```
const foo : {a: number} = {a: 1}
const bar : string = "bar"
const foobar = {...foo, bar}
console.log(foobar)
// foobar is type {bar: string, a: number}
```

Why does this case work, and the first case doesn't?

Comment: Here you can find explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129738/spread-operator-not-type-safe
AFAIK, spread operator is not type safe (can't find issue yet).
This issue may be related to indexed type: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40529

Comment: Indexed types are unsafe )

Comment: They are unsafe, check. Is there a particular reason for this? Why is the spread operator sometimes safe, like in example 2?

Comment: Here you can find more info about excess properry checking https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks

Comment: The main problem is that TypeScript cannot guarantee *in general* that a type only has a given set of properties. For example `interface Foo {a: number; b: string}` suggests something with type `Foo` has an `a` and `b` property. However `{a: 1, b: "two", c: false}` is assignable to `Foo`. The compiler will not allow you to access `c` but it cannot assume it's *not* there. When getting all keys of an object there is no type safety in the general case. That leads to some behaviours that seem odd looking at types alone but are better suited for the real world code.

Comment: Quick demonstration of how an object that is assignable to an interface can have unexpected set of keys in some circumstances: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=36&pln=15&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyycAXMiAK4C2ARtANwFE1kDOYUoA5gQL4EJ0IdsnQ0AVgEZkAXhylkkgDTIWyAERgA7unUqEZeABtWEXo3yDhYURIBMs5AHkJEBGAB0CKBDiQAFGJSAJQWAkIiMJiSZBhYckGS9MgA9ClwRkboWhAAJgTh1sgA1tJyLuJunsUQAJ6s-lHokqGpKeycIFwA2gC6yIWs6EYQHllc-uqleiUtyWlwKjT6BZYRNk12sZiOQXbz6ZnZeatWIsUO5a7uHjX1jZh2rWkd3H0Da8LDo+OTFyQzC7PFIAHhA6DAAAtuAA+IA)

Comment: Thank you @VLAZ! That answers my question. Would you like to submit an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @VLAZ TS compiler also cannot guarantee if object of type Foo { optionalProp?: string } has actual property optionalProp. But this type with optional property works fine with spread operator. So I think it is odd.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because construction with spread cannot handle 'property declaration priority' properly.
(indexed type properties have lower priority declaration). I think it can be improved  in future versions.
Try this:

```
const foobar = { ...foo, bar } as (typeof foo & { bar: typeof bar});
```