# Typescript + Zod schema - when using a generic schema as a parameter, the spread operator bypasses typechecking

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, zod

I am trying to define a function that takes some Zod schema, and an object that abides by the zod schema. However typescript doesn't seem to actually check the object abides by the schema if I'm using a spread operator.

In the example below, myTestFunc takes a `schema` which is any Zod schema, and `newItem` which is an item who's type is inferred from `schema`.
Typescript happily prevents me sending in an item with an extra made up property (`city: "Paris"`). However, when I use a spread operator `...{city: "Paris"}` it seems to totally thwart Typescript and it just lets it through!

```
import { z } from "zod";

const myTestFunc = <U extends z.AnyZodObject>(
  schema: U,
  newItem: z.infer<U>,
) => {
  console.log("some processing here");
};

const schemaA = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  age: z.number(),
});


myTestFunc(schemaA, {
  name: "John",
  age: 25,
  city: "Paris", // <- error, as "city" is not an allowed part of the type
});

myTestFunc(schemaA, {
  name: "John",
  age: 25,
  ...{city: "Paris"}, // <- no error, so weird
});
```

This is rather annoying as it means everytime I'm working with generic Zod objects I'm not getting proper typechecking.

I also tried this slightly different way of writing the problem:

```
import { z } from "zod";

type MyTestFuncParams<U extends z.AnyZodObject> = {
  schema: U;
  newItem: z.infer<U>;
}

const myTestFunc = <U extends z.AnyZodObject>(
  {schema,
  newItem}: MyTestFuncParams<U>,
) => {
  console.log("some processing here");
};

const schemaA = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  age: z.number(),
});

const brokenItem = {
  name: "John",
  age: 25,
  city: "Paris",
};

myTestFunc({schema: schemaA, newItem: brokenItem}); // <- no error!
```

[what typescript is expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UHmq.png)

[actual item contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC0aR.png)

It doesn't type error! Very odd behaviour. My IDE (vscode) can tell the types clearly mismatch.

How can I write this function such that it actually checks my types properly? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
myTestFunc(schemaA, {
  name: "John",
  age: 25,
  ...{city: "Paris"}, // <- no error, so weird
});
```

When you are do that, you are essentially saying that the `newItem` is being passed `as`  `z.infer<U>`.

```
const tempCity: z.infer<typeof schemaA> = {
  name: "John",
  age: 25,
  ...{ city: "Paris" }, // <- no error
};
```

If you hover over the `tempCity` on the above code in a code editor, you can see that despite `tempCity` having the `city` property typescript does not know about it. It only knows about the other two properties.

```
const tempCity2: z.infer<typeof schemaA> = {
  name: "John",
  age: 25,
  city: "Paris", // <- error
};
```

Typescript provides you with the red squiggly when you are passing the object literal, because at that time typescript is able to tell that the shape of the data does not match the type. This can be proven if you hover over the type of `tempCity2`. Typescript knows that for the type that `city` should not be in the object.

```
const tempCity3 = {
  name: "John",
  age: 25,
  city: "Paris",  // <- no error
} as z.infer<typeof schemaA>;
```

If you hover over `tempCity3`, despite the object having 3 properties, type hinting will only provide you with `name` an `age`. This happens because when you use `as` you are telling typescript that you know better than it about what type your data is. This will however only work if your object implements all the properties of the type you want to force it to.
Its for this same reason that the second version of your function doesn't throw an error.

I hope this clarified the type part of your question. Your function is already type checking properly.

[Spread operator not type safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129738/spread-operator-not-type-safe)